# What is novel about the analysis showing that Mercury is "closer" to Earth than Venus?

Tags: astronomy, history, solar-system

Why is the [recent analysis](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/do/10.1063/PT.6.3.20190312a/full/) showing that Mercury and not Venus is on average the closest planet considered new?

This should surely come as no surprise to anyone who has ever looked at a plot of the paths of Venus and Mercury in an Earth centered coordinate system (such as the Ptolemaic model's): while Venus periodically swings closer to earth than Mercury in such plots, it spends much more time farther away.

This can easily be seen in a simple example with approximate modeled (circular coplanar) orbits over the course of several (here the past and future 4) years

[image]

(actual ephemerides are basically the same, though more ragged) and also in analogous visualizations that have been readily available for over four centuries:

[image]

What am I missing? What is novel about the current methods or conclusions of the current analysis?

Comment: "As it turns out, by some phenomenon of carelessness, ambiguity, or groupthink, science popularizers have disseminated information based on a flawed assumption about the average distance between planets." Jeez, that article is really hyping a pedentic conclusion.

Comment: Of course what people mean by "Venus is the closest planet" is that Venus is the planet that can get the closest to Earth. I don't see the point of the linked article at all.

Comment: @knzhou: I'm not disputing the claims of the article (that's for another discussion altogether), I'm asking why those claims (or the analysis that produces them) are considered new (and newsworthy), especially since one can see them clearly in a picture that's 400 years old (representing a model that's nearly 2000 years old).

Comment: They’re not. Not every article in a magazine (which is exactly what this is) is groundbreaking. Even Science’s magazine publishes a lot of stinkers. A scientific journal would typically have higher standards.

Comment: Nothing novel at all, except perhaps the definition of "closest".  Papers like this are useful because they may suggest a different way of looking at things, but IMHO they don't really offer anything new.

Comment: @S.McGrew: So there is something different from what's in the figures above? That's what I'm asking: whether their definition is different from what's shown there.

Comment: I think there is nothing different from what's in the figures you supplied.  The article is just pointing out what comes as no surprise to you, me, or the other commenters, and  is playing with semantics.

Comment: It's entirely unclear why the redefinition of *the closest* as *having the least mean linear separation over time* is deemed "better" without any argument. Why not average over some other parameter, or take the harmonic mean (because harmony of celestial spheres), or RMS, or use some other irrelevant math technique to prove a meaningless and inconsequential point? I usually give paper authors the benefit of doubt and do not say "this paper is nothing but nonsense," but this paper is nothing but nonsense!